# How to disable vertical scrolling on touch screens in Iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have this:

```css
#outerdiv
{
  width:254px;
  height: 75px;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 23px;
}

#inneriframe
{
  position:absolute;
  top:-175px;
  left:-870px;
  width:1280px;
  height: 261px !important;
}
```

```html
<div id='outerdiv' class='well'>
  <iframe target='_blank' id='inneriframe' scrolling='no' style='border:none;scroll:none;' id='if' sandbox='allow-forms allow-scripts' src='http://sec.com'></iframe>
</div>
```

This will show only a selected area of the Iframe content.
I can't scroll inside the Iframe horizontally and that's what I want 
**But** I can scroll the content **vertically** :/

How to disable it so no one can scroll the page inside the Iframe?

Comment: have you tried using overflow:hidden on the iframe element itself? You can then target touch screens using something like modernizr then apply the css rule to only touch screen devices.

Comment: @mmmoustache I try this option but always the vertical overflow still working.
This happens only on old mobile browsers.